# symfony2 gmail send email not working

Tags: symfony, email, fosuserbundle, send

i try to send email with  the fosuserbundle but it's not working .
this is my file configuration :

config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
     transport:  "%mailer_transport%"
     encryption: "%mailer_encryption%"
     host:       "%mailer_host%"
     username:   "%mailer_user%"
     password:   "%mailer_password%"


fos_user:
     db_driver: orm
     firewall_name: main
     user_class: Session\UserBundle\Entity\User
     registration:
         confirmation:
             enabled: true
```

parameters.yml

```
  parameters:
      database_driver: pdo_mysql
      database_host: 127.0.0.1
      database_port: null
      database_name: ensaj
      database_user: root
      database_password: null
      mailer_encryption: ssl
      mailer_auth_mode: login
      mailer_transport: gmail
      mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
      mailer_user: xxxxxxx@gmail.com
      mailer_password: 1xxxxxxx

      locale: fr
      secret: 2ca840346e95efa11df5c5f12a572ea5dcf64e83
```

any idea please ; 
by the way i change my gmail configuration to active pop and imap but no way .
and sometimes i have a message to my email that notice :blocked connection attempt

Comment: In your switmailer configuration you missed port parameter. "port: %mailer_port%" and "auth_mode:  %mailer_auth_mode%". and in your parameters.yml it will be mailer_port: 465.
And in your "mailer_transport : smtp"  will work  instead of gmail.

Comment: @herr - you don't need all of these parameters when using `gmail` transport http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html

Comment: @tomasz-madeyski - Thanks for the update. i was not aware for gmail parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me it works like:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
```

when using mailer_transport == gmail

optionally you may have to allow that account beeing used for your app,
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255